# Launch a specific browser using Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uitest

I want to open a ChromeDriver session, then navigate to a URL and locate a few Web Elements on the page using Swift. 
Selenium is not supported for Swift. Tried using XCTest but it only works for testing a custom App. How do I just open say google.com on chrome browser using Swift? Can this be done on the XCode playground without creating a project?

Comment: What happens if the user doesn't have the specified browser though? That might create an issue in the future.

Comment: I have chrome installed and I'm looking for ways to open a site on an already installed browser. I've tried this on the Xcode playground but it doesn't really open the browser.                                                                                 
 if let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com") {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
}